# Insert data using LINQ with stored procedures while using two projects in c#

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures

I have two projects (tiers) in my application. one is `myApplication` and the other is `myApplicationLib`.

I have all the forms in `myApplication` tier and I am writing the business classes in `myApplicationLib` tier. Now I want to insert the values from `myApplication` form into SQL Server via `myApplicationLib` using LINQ with stored procedures.

How can I call the stored procedure on the DataContext from one tier to another tier?

Please help me. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

To keep an abstraction of your data access/business logic from presentation, myApplicationLib will wrap all data access (including context and LINQ) and expose Entities/Models/DTOs via methods.  For instance, if you have a table of products you need to access and show on a web form you can:

- Create a method called GetCategoryProducts that returns a list of Products in myApplicationLib (you would call a stored procedure here and/or use LINQ)
- Reference myApplicationLib in myApplication
- Call the GetCategoryProducts method in myApplicationLib and display on the web form in myApplication (you can use LINQ on the returned list of products if needed).

I recommend looking into the [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) which is common design used for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you would typically do:
1. assign values from Application Form to the required properties of ApplicationLib object
2. Create LINQ Entity
3. Call ExecuteMethod

Obviously things may not be as straight forward as mentioned but it will get you started.
More information [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37938/Simple-6-steps-to-use-stored-procedure-in-LINQ)

Answer (score 0):

You can build a method like this and put it in your Datalayer or.. and call that from your business.

```
     public bool CallSp(string command, params object[] parameters)
        {
            int i;
            string com = command + " ";
            for (i = 0; i < parameters.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                com += string.Format("{{0}} ,", i);
            }
            com += string.Format("{{0}}", i);

            //ctx is the datacontext
            //EF5
            ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(com, parameters);
            return true;
        }

        CallSp("exec SP", p1, p2, p3,...);
```

Comment: Sir Iam trying this code.. Iam not able to get Database.ExecuteSqlCommand keyword. Iam not wring dataAccess class for database connection. May be this is the reason why Iam not getting Database.ExecuteSqlCommand keyword

Comment: which ORM do you use for this application?

Comment: if its EF tell me what is the version?

Comment: Iam using Visual Studio 2008 windows application .net 3.5 version sir